# numpy installed but cant be imported on VSC

Tags: python, numpy, visual-studio-code

```py
import numpy as np
```

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

But when I

```
pip install numpy
```

> Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\anato\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (1.21.2)

However, when I use pyso(for school) it does work

so I reckon there is a problem with the path on VSC:

```
import os
for i in os.environ.get('PATH').split('C:'):
    print(f'C:{i}')
```

> PS C:\Users\anato> & C:/Users/anato/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe "c:/Users/anato/OneDrive/Documents/info/other/import os.py"
> C:
> C:\Windows\system32;
> C:\Windows;
> C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
> C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
> C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;
> C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
> C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;
> C:\WINDOWS\system32;
> C:\WINDOWS;
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;
> C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;
> C:\Users\anato\AppData\Roaming\ActiveState\bin;
> C:\Users\anato\AppData\Local\activestate\bin;
> C:\Users\anato\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts;
> C:\Users\anato\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38;
> C:\Users\anato\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;
> C:\Users\anato\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin

I don't know what I should do so please help

Comment: Since you use Windows and VSCode, You should set up a **virtual environment** inside VSCode and install the packages in it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Is this question resolved?

Answer (score 1):

**Numpy** was installed in **python3.8** in vscode, but you used **python3.9** as interpreter, that’s why it threw No module error.You need to install virtual environment properly in your **vscode** .For install virtual environment in your **vscode** run the following command in your vscode terminal `pip3 install pipenv`.

[image]

if you get other help about pip command you can type `pip3 help`. Pip3 is the Python3 version of pip. You can more details about Virtual Environments in this article  [Virtual Environments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNXUh.png)

And then install numpy in vscode terminal use this command `pip3 install numpy`

[image]

Aftar that you can **import numpy**

[image]

Comment: well i got this: WARNING: The script virtualenv-clone.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\anato\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
  WARNING: The script virtualenv.exe is installed in 'C:\Users\anato\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python38\Scripts' which is not on PATH.  and numpy still cant be imported